# Формирование вложенных в список списков из других списков по определенным правилам?

Tags: python, алгоритм, список, списки

Добрый день,
есть три списка

```
allIndex_A = [1, 2, 8, 12, 17, 21, 23, 29]
allIndex_B = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
allIndex_C = [4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 19, 25, 27]
```

нужно из них сделать список со вложенными списками, вот такой:

```
newList = [[1,3,4], [2,3,4], [8,9,10], [12,13,14], ...]
```

Первый элемент вложенного списка это первый это первый элемент списка allIndex_A.
Второй элемент это первый элемент из списка allIndex_В, значение которого больше значения первого элемента из вложенного списка.
Третий элемент это также первый найденный элемент из списка allIndex_С, значение которого больше первого элемента во вложенном списке.

Первый элемент второго вложенного списка это второй элемент из списка allIndex_A.
Второй и третий элемент второго вложенного списка находятся по таким же условиям как и в первом вложенном списке. То есть это должен быть первый найденный элемент из списков allIndex_В и allIndex_С, значение которого больше значения первого элемента.

Пример получившегося списка newList выше.
Начал изучать программирование недавно, многих вещей еще не знаю. Буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит как сделать то, что мне нужно или хотя-бы даст ссылку где можно почитать на тему вопроса.

Comment: А списки гарантировано отсортированные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение, основанное на [использовании `zip()`, чтобы транспонировать элементы трёх списков](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from itertools import tee

def gt_first(first, iterable):
    """Yield items from iterable that are greater than corresponding items from
       first.

    first, iterable are sorted.
    """
    it = iter(iterable)
    x = next(it) #NOTE: wrap with try/except StopIteration for pep-479
    for item in first:
        while not (x > item):
            x = next(it)
        yield x

allIndex_A = [1, 2, 8, 12, 17, 21, 23, 29]
allIndex_B = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
allIndex_C = [4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 19, 25, 27]

a, ab, ac = tee(allIndex_A, 3)
L = list(map(list, zip(a, gt_first(ab, allIndex_B), gt_first(ac, allIndex_C))))
print(L)
```

#### Результат

```
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [8, 9, 10], [12, 13, 14], [17, 18, 19], [21, 22, 25],
 [23, 24, 25]]
```

В ответе нет вложенного списка `[29, 30, None]`, так как `allIndex_C` не имеет элемента большего `29` (можно `itertools.zip_longest()` вместо `zip()` использовать, чтобы подставить какое-нибудь значение, вместо игнорирования вложенного списка целиком).

Время исполнения линейное (`O(n)`). Если входные списки не отсортированы, то их надо отсортировать, тогда время исполнения `O(n*log n)` (на сортировку).

Answer (score 0):

Пример алгоритма для двух списков. Его можно расширить и до трёх:

```
allIndex_A = [1, 2, 8, 12, 17, 21, 23, 29]
allIndex_B = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]

def mylist(il1, il2):
    for i in il1:
        for j in il2:
            if j>i:
                yield [i,j]
                break

print list(mylist(allIndex_A, allIndex_B))
# [[1, 3], [2, 3], [8, 9], [12, 13], [17, 18], [21, 22], [23, 24], [29, 30]]
```

Проблемы в примере:

1. Используется два списка вместо трёх;
2. Трудоёмкость квадратичная вместо линейной или псевдолинейной.

В случае расширения для трёх списков, `break` должен выходить из двух вложенных циклов. Для этого, [возможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops-in-python), придётся использовать флаговую переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что удалось набросать:

```
def merge_lists(l1, l2):
    for item in l1:
        for item2 in l2:
            if type(item) is int:
                if item < item2:
                    yield [item, item2]
                    break
            else:
                if item[-1] < item2:
                    x = list(item)
                    x.append(item2)
                    yield x
                    break

l1 = [1, 2, 8, 12, 17, 21, 23, 29]
l2 = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
l3 = [4, 6, 10, 14, 16, 19, 25, 27]


list(merge_lists(l1, l2))

Вывод:
[[1, 3], [2, 3], [8, 9], [12, 13], [17, 18], [21, 22], [23, 24], [29, 30]]

list(merge_lists(merge_lists(l1, l2), l3))

Вывод:
[[1, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [8, 9, 10],
 [12, 13, 14],
 [17, 18, 19],
 [21, 22, 25],
 [23, 24, 25]]
```

Вариант 2, на 3 списка:

```
def merge_lists(l1, l2, l3):
    for item1 in l1:
        for item2 in l2:
            if item2 > item1:
                for item3 in l3:
                    if item3 > item2:
                        yield [item1, item2, item3]
                        break
                break

list(merge_lists(l1, l2, l3))

Вывод:

[[1, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [8, 9, 10],
 [12, 13, 14],
 [17, 18, 19],
 [21, 22, 25],
 [23, 24, 25]]
```