# Передвижение по элементам внутри for. Как реализовать *next++ в Питоне

Tags: c++, python

В си-подобных языках предоставляется возможность определить изменение переменной в объявлении `for`, а далее в самом цикле изменять её значение. Пример на С++11:

```
std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3,3,3,4,5};
auto next=a.begin(); next++;
for(auto i=a.begin();i!=a.end();i++, next++){
    while (next != a.end() && *i == *next) {
           i++;
           next++;
    }
    std::cout << *i<<std::endl;
}
```

Как можно реализовать такое же перемещение по элементам `tuple, string etc` в Python?

Так как единственное, что приходит в голову :

```
a = "Python is cool"
prev = ""
for elem in a:
    if elem == prev:
        continue
    print(elem)
    prev = elem
```

Comment: Понятно, что можно использовать `while`,  но меня интересуют возможности с `for`-ом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы убрать подряд идущие дубликаты, [можно `itertools.groupby()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

def uniq_adjacent(iterable):
    return (first for first, same_adjacent_items in groupby(iterable))
```

Пример:

```py
>>> numbers =  1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5
>>> print(*uniq_adjacent(numbers))
1 2 3 4 5
```

Остались только первые вхождения из повторяющихся элементов, которые рядом находятся. Обычно это пишется как:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

def uniq_adjacent(iterable):
    return map(itemgetter(0), groupby(iterable))
```

Результат тот же. См. ещё [`unique_justseen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) itertools' рецепт, чтобы поддерживать произвольный ключ для сравнения.

Чтобы руками такое реализовать:

```py
def uniq_adjacent(iterable):
    last = object()
    for item in iterable:
        if item != last:
            yield item
            last = item
```

Использование абсолютно такое как и у предыдущих вариантов. Обратите внимание, *индекс нигде явно не используется*. Этот вариант аналогичен Питон-коду из вопроса (работает и для tuple, strings, etc).

Если хочется реализовать без использования `for`-цикла:

```py
class uniq_adjacent:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.last = self.current = object()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.last == self.current:
            self.current = next(self.it)  # exit on StopIteration
        self.last = self.current
        return self.current
```

Работает также. Аналогом `*next++` из C++ здесь является `next(iterator)`.

Вот совершенно неидиоматичный Питон-код, который старается построчно близко форму  C++ кода повторить, чтобы показать что возможно for-цикл и `next()` совместить для одно и того же итератора (здесь и как правило это плохая идея):

```py
from itertools import tee, zip_longest

def uniq_adjacent_do_not_use(iterable, sentinel=object()):
    # XXX DO NOT USE 
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    for x, y in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=sentinel):  # iterate pairwise
        while x == y:
            x = next(a)
            y = next(b, sentinel)
        yield x
```

Для проверки, посмотрите сможете ли вы понять как работает решение, использующее tee(), zip(), next() в [Формирование вложенных в список списков из других списков по определенным правилам?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/413867/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Изменение переменной, которая определяет условие работы цикла внутри тела цикла - **плохой стиль** программирования.

Python, который позиционирует себя как "язык для чистого и красивого программирования", не может разрешить вам делать такие вещи легко. Python не дает такого же контроля над циклом `for`, как это делают другие языки.

Вообще, `for` предназначен исключительно для итерирования над итерируемыми структурами данных (список, генератор, etc.).

В данном случае, вам придется использовать цикл `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Так можно:

```
it = iter(range(0, 10))
for elem in it:
    print('for[0]: ', elem)
    if elem == 1:
        for elem1 in it:
            print('for[1]: ', elem1)
            if elem1 == 6:
                break
```