# Различия между циклами for и while

Tags: python, while, for

Объясните пожалуйста различия между циклами `for` и `while`.

Если можно простым языком. Спасибо.

Comment: связанные вопросы [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044);
 [Передвижение по элементам внутри for. Как реализовать *next++ в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/716998/23044)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

На примере функции `range(n)`:

В цикле `for i in range(n)` в переменную `i` будет поочередно записываться каждое значение из диапазона `range(n)`, например:

```
In [1]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     print(i)      
   ...:                   
0                         
1                         
2
```

Сначала `i` принимает значение `0`, затем `1`, и так пока не дойдем до `n`.

Также циклом `for` можно пройтись по любому итерабельному объекту, например:

```
In [4]: array = [1, 2, 3]

In [5]: for i in array:
   ...:     print(i)
```

В переменную `i` поочередно будет записаны значения из списка `array`.

Цикл `while` работает немного иначе, он проверяет условие на истинность, `while x < 10` - на каждой итерации цикла, будет осуществлена проверка `x < 10`, если это так, цикл пойдет дальше, на примере того же `range(n)`:

```
In [2]: i = 0

In [3]: while i < 3:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...:     i += 1
   ...:
0
1
2
```

На каждой итерации мы проверяем меньше ли переменная `i` чем `3`, если это так, то выводим значение переменной `i` и прибавляем к ней единицу, повторяем это пока проверка на `i < 3` не вернёт `False`. Мы по сути говорим, пока что-то истинно, то выполняй какие то действия.

Помните пример с циклом `for` когда мы проходили по списку? С `while` дело обстоит иначе, нам нужно вытягивать из списка элементы по их индексам, т.е в условие будет выглядеть так: `while i < len(array)`, функция `len(iterable)` вернёт нам кол-во элементов в списке, на примере того же `array`:

```
In [6]: i = 0

In [7]: while i < len(array):
   ...:     print(array[i])
   ...:     i += 1
```

Чтобы определить бесконечный цикл `while`, нужно указать такое условие, которое всегда истинно, например `while True`.

С циклом `for` все сложнее, бесконечный цикл явно указать нельзя, так как цикл `for` закончит свою работу тогда, когда пройдет по всем элементам объекта, следовательно нужно ему передать такой объект, в котором бесконечно элементов, тут нам помогут [генераторы](https://lancelote.gitbooks.io/intermediate-python/content/book/generators.html), говорить о них детально я не буду, так как тема довольно обширная, лишь покажу небольшой пример с модулем `itertools`:

```
In [11]: from itertools import count

In [12]: for i in count():
    ...:     print(i) # 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
```

Таким образом мы определили бесконечный цикл `for`, `count` также принимает 2 необязательных аргумента, `start` число с которого начнём итерацию, и `step` собственно шаг.

[Тут](https://younglinux.info/python/task/cycles) Вы можете найти немного задачек на циклы для практики.

Answer (score 4):

Общее у `while` и `for` конструкций, что они обе задают циклы. Всё остальное разное.

`while`-цикл крайне простой и общий:

```
пока <условие истинно>:
    <выполняем тело цикла>
```

Пример:

```
while t.is_alive():
    t.join(0.04)
```

`for`-цикл более специализированный:

```
для <каждого элемента> в <перечислимом объекте>:
    <выполняем тело цикла>
```

Пример:

```
 for n in numbers:
     print(n * n)
```

Можно выразить `for`-цикл, используя `while`-цикл:

```
it = iter(numbers)         # получаем итератор
while True:
    try:
        n = next(it)       # получаем следующий элемент
    except StopIteration:  # нет больше элементов
         break             # выходим из цикла
    print(n * n)
```

И наоборот, [чтобы показать, что это вообще возможно] можно `while` цикл как `for`-цикл записать:

```
for _ in UntilDead(t):  # запрашиваем элементы у UntilDead 
    pass                # и ничего не делаем
```

где `UntilDead` класс определяет соответствующий [итератор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/):

```
class UntilDead:
    def __init__(self, thread, timeout=.4):
        self.thread = thread
        self.timeout = timeout
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if not self.thread.is_alive():
            raise StopIteration
        return self.thread.join(self.timeout)
```

Для работы `for`-цикла используется [«протокол итератора»](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement): в `for`-цикл можно передать любой объект, из которого итератор можно извлечь (эквивалент вызова [iter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)). В примере, `UntilDead` уже является [итератором](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (определяет `__iter__` метод, который возвращает самого себя). На каждой итерации вызывается [`__next__` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__), чтобы следующий элемент получить до тех пор пока не возникнет `StopIteration` исключение.

Специальные методы (начинаются и заканчиваются на `__`) во многих встроенных протоколах участвуют в Питоне. См. [Магические методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Использование объекта в конструкции `for`,
 требует у него наличия атрибута `__iter__`.

```
def q1():
    yield from [1, 2]

for a in q1():
    print(a)
print(hasattr(q1(), '__iter__'))  # True

print(print(hasattr(1, '__iter__')))  # False
for a in 1:
    print(a)  # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

q2 = [1, 2]
print(hasattr(q2, '__iter__'))  # True
# for можно использовать в списковых включениях
a = [b + 1 for b in q2]
```

Использование объекта в конструкции `while`,
требует у него наличия атрибута `__bool__`.
`while` нельзя использовать в списковых включениях.

Comment: for-цикл не требует `__iter__`. `class C: __getitem__ =  lambda self, i: i`

Answer (score 0):

---

`while` - это цикл*, который повторяет что-то, пока что-то верно. Например**:

```
count = 0
flag = True
while flag == True: #это цикл, который делает то, что отмечено отступом пока flag == True.
   if count == 15:
       break    #если сount равен 15, выходить из цикла while.
   print("пока верно")
   count += 1
```

---

`for` - цикл, который повторяется несколько раз. Например:

```
for i in range (5): #5 раз печатает "hello"
   print ("hello")
```

---

*-цикл - что-то, что повторяется.

**-после `#` показаны комментарии, это не код.

**Надеюсь, стало понятно!**