# Почему итератор не выдает элементы как я хочу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, итераторы

Код

```
class CitiesManager(object):
    """Класс, содержащий функциональность работы с городами."""

    def __init__(self, cities):
        self.cities = cities

    def __getitem__(self, item: int):
        """Получить элемент по индексу.

        Args:
            item (int): индекс элемента для получения в операциях среза.
        """
        return self.cities[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cities)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Возвратить себя как объект итератора."""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Получить следующий элемент """
        for item in self.cities:
            yield item

cities = ['Петрозаводск', 'Хельсинки', 'Санкт-Петербург']
north_cities = CitiesManager(cities)


for city in north_cities:
    print(city)
```

выводит подобное:

```
<generator object __next__ at 0x7f13de432d58>
<generator object __next__ at 0x7f13de432c50>
<generator object __next__ at 0x7f13de432d58>
<generator object __next__ at 0x7f13de432c50>
<generator object __next__ at 0x7f13de432d58>
```

Почему? 
Я хочу, что бы он выводил строки "Петрозаводск", "Хельсинки", "Санкт-Петербург"

Comment: что мешает `print(*cities)` написать?

Comment: @jfs вероятно, мешает желание разобраться с итераторами.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev: `cities` это список, а не итератор. [Синтаксис со звёздочкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044) можно не использовать. Вопрос, почему нельзя `for city in cities: print(city)` написать?

Comment: 1) Я хочу использовать данный класс как контейнер множества городов и добавить к этому классу другой функционал, например фильтрацию по населению и т.д. 2) я хочу хорошо понять как работают итераторы

Comment: @jfs именно потому, что `cities` - это список, а не итератор, пытаясь разобраться с итераторами, нельзя написать `print(*cities)` или `for city in cities: print(city)`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev для тех из нас кто мысли автора не умеет читать вопрос должен быть в самом вопросе с помощью слов написан¶ К примеру ваш ответ вводит в заблуждение так как класс в нём не определяет итератор. Не ясно хочет автор именно итератор создать или что-то другое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что метод `__next__` должен возвращать текущее значение итерации, а вы возвращаете новый генератор.

Есть два способа решить эту проблему. Во-первых, возвращать в качестве итератора не себя, а генератор:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for item in self.cities:
        yield item
```

Во-вторых, контролировать своё состояние, как положено итератору:

```
class CitiesManager(object):
    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        """Возвратить себя как объект итератора."""
        self._item_index = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Получить следующий элемент """
        self._item_index += 1
        if len(self.cities) <= self._item_index:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.cities[self._item_index]
```

**UPDATE:** Как верно заметил @AndrioSkur, ещё более правильный вариант - это возвращать из метода `__iter__` новый итератор при каждом вызове.

```
class CitiesManagerIter(object):
    def __init__(self, cmanager):
        self.cmanager = cmanager
        self.__current_index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Получить следующий элемент """
        self.__current_index += 1
        if len(self.cmanager.cities) <= self.__current_index:
            raise StopIteration
        return self.cmanager.cities[self.__current_index]


class CitiesManager(object):
    ...

    def __iter__(self):
        """Возвратить объект итератора."""
        return CitiesManagerIter(self)
```

Comment: @AndrioSkur автор не хочет каноническую схему с отдельным итератором, ему нужен именно объект итерирующий сам себя.

Comment: я чет не вижу этого по комментам, а если по коду то ТС мог и не знать/сталкиваться с таким нюансом. И было б неплохо чтобы те кто заходили с поиска, видели норм вариант, а не скрытые баги. Впрочем, вам решать.

Comment: @AndrioSkur дополнил ответ.

Comment: 1- первый пример не определяет у вас итератор так как `__iter__` каждый раз новый генератор возвращает 2- второй пример нарушает протокол итератора: выбросив StopIteration однажды, итератор обязан продолжать выбрасывать StopIteration (и если `self._item_index` не определён в `__init__`, то `next(it)` может AttributeError выбросить у вас) 3- в третьем примере CitiesManager снова не итератор (очевидно), но хотя бы `CitiesManagerIter` на итератор похож (хорошо). Хотя чтобы итерация для кода в вопросе заработала было бы достаточно вообще `__iter__`, `__next__` убрать методы.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы итерация заработала, достаточно *убрать* несовместимые или сломанные `__iter__`, `__next__` методы из кода в вопросе.

Наличие `__getitem__` и `__len__` методов указывает, что вы хотите создать *последовательность* ([Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)), а не *итератор* (`__next__` метод возвращает (`return`) следующее значение (если есть) или выбрасывает `StopIteration` исключение (если нет), `__iter__` возвращает `self` для итераторов).

Одну и ту же последовательность вы можете обходить многократно. Вы можете получать индивидуальные элементы по индексу из последовательности:

```
>>> R = range(3)
>>> print(*R)
0 1 2
>>> print(*R)
0 1 2
>>> R[0]
0
```

[Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)

Итератор можно обойти ровно один раз. Когда элементы закончатся и  итератор выбросил StopIteration, он будет продолжать выбрасывать StopIteration (сигнализируя конец итерации):

```
>>> iterator = iter(range(3))
>>> print(*iterator)
0 1 2
>>> print(*iterator)

>>> iterator[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'range_iterator' object is not subscriptable
'range_iterator' object is not subscriptable
```

Второй `print` печатает только новую строчку так как первый `print`  все элементы забрал из итератора. Итератор в отличии от последовательностей не поддерживает индексацию.

> 1) Я хочу использовать данный класс как контейнер множества городов и добавить к этому классу другой функционал, например фильтрацию по населению и т.д.

В Питоне не обязательно класс создавать, если у вас есть последовательность, которую вы хотите по какому-то критерию отфильтровать (если вы видите слово Manager в названии класса, это хороший повод задуматься, а нужен ли этот класс вообще). К примеру, имея список городов, с указанными именами и широтами:

```
from collections import namedtuple

City = namedtuple('City', 'name latitude')
cities = [
    City('Петрозаводск', 61.77), 
    City('Хельсинки', 60.17),
    City('Санкт-Петербург', 59.95)
]
```

легко найти  самый северный город в этом списке городов:

```
northernmost_city = max(cities, key=lambda city: city.latitude)
```

Или если вы хотите напечатать имена городов в алфавитном порядке, также новый класс не нужно создавать:

```
for city in sorted(cities):
    print(city.name)
```

Вывод:

```
Петрозаводск
Санкт-Петербург
Хельсинки
```

> 2) я хочу хорошо понять как работают итераторы

Если вы хотите создать итератор, то уберите из кода в вопросе  `__getitem__`, `__len__` методы, а в методе `__next__` возвращайте следующее значение. К примеру, вот бесконечный итератор:

```
class Ones:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        return 1
```

Пример:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> print(*islice(Ones(), 10))
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы закончился итератор, то следует выбросить StopIteration (и продолжать выбрасывать при последующих обращениях):

```
class EmptyIterator:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        raise StopIteration
```

Этот класс определяет пустой итератор (нет элементов, сразу StopIteration выбрасывается):

```
>>> print(*EmptyIterator())

>>>
```

Комбинируя первые два примера итераторов, можно определить аналог итератора для списков в чистом Питоне:

```
class ListIterator:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.i = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        if self.i < len(self.lst):
            item = lst[self.i]
        else:
            raise StopIteration
        self.i += 1
        return item
```

Пример:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> it = ListIterator(lst)
>>> print(*it)
1 2 3
>>> print(*it)

>>> print(*lst)
1 2 3
```

Видно, что после первого обхода, элементы в итераторе закончились (второй `print` только новую строку печатает) и это никак не влияет на исходный список. И наоборот, изменение списка во время обхода итератора может оказать влияние на то что возвращается: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044).

Посмотрите ещё примеры и ссылки в ответе (особенно [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)): [Различия между циклами for и while](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/790920/23044).

Answer (score 0):

Во первых, `__next__(self)` обычная функция, это значит, она хочет `return`, нет `yield`.

Во вторых, итератор должен во вашем случае окончиться, значит, метод `__next__(self)` должен в какое-то время возбудить исключение `StopIteration`.

И так, ваш код после мелких переделок в 2 местах (см. 2 комментарии в нем) может быть например таким :

```
class CitiesManager(object):
    """Класс, содержащий функциональность работы с городами."""

    def __init__(self, cities):
        self.cities = cities
        self.i      = -1                        // Добавлено

    def __getitem__(self, item: int):
        """Получить элемент по индексу.

        Args:
            item (int): индекс элемента для получения в операциях среза.
        """
        return self.cities[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cities)

    def __iter__(self):
        """Возвратить себя как объект итератора."""
        return self

    def __next__(self):                         // Изменено содержание метода
        """Получить следующий элемент """
        self.i += 1
        if self.i < len(self.cities):
            return self.cities[self.i]
        else:
            self.i = -1
            raise StopIteration

cities = ['Петрозаводск', 'Хельсинки', 'Санкт-Петербург']
north_cities = CitiesManager(cities)


for city in north_cities:
    print(city)
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, т.к. пройти через north_cities можно только один раз

Comment: @pynix - Спасибо вам, я правил мой ответ (добавил `self.i = -1` перед `raise StopIteration`).

Comment: вы нарушаете спеку на итераторы. Конкретно этот пункт: `iter(object) is not iter(object)`