# Найти наибольшие значения X и Y, удовлетворяющие системе неравенств

Tags: python

Задачка решается с помощью системы неравенств. Есть несколько неравенств, и ответом будет наибольшее значение X и Y, при которых R = X+Y максимально
 Ексель например легко даёт ответ с помощью поиска решений.
Но в питоне такой опции, как я понимаю, нет. Можете Подсказать, как возможно реализовать алгоритм решения такой задачи?
Вот неравенства для примера:

```
2X+3Y <= 9;  
3X+2Y <= 13;  
x-y <= 1;  
y <= 2;
```

Comment: Вообще, если без неравенств то Метод Гаусса для решения Систем линейных уравнений, хотя если и с ними, то просто после решения условия неравенств наложить

Comment: related: [linear programming in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10697995/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос можно свести к задаче [линейного программирования](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html): найти наибольшую сумму `x+y` (наименьшее `-x-y`) при заданных ограничениях на x,y:

```
>>> import scipy.optimize
>>> scipy.optimize.linprog([-1,-1], A_ub=[[2,3],[3,2],[1,-1],[0,1]], b_ub=[9,13,1,2])
     fun: -3.8
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 2
   slack: array([0. , 3. , 0. , 0.6])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([2.4, 1.4])
```

То же самое, используя [PuLP пакет](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp):

```
import pulp  # $ pip install pulp

problem = pulp.LpProblem("test1", pulp.LpMaximize)
x = pulp.LpVariable('x')
y = pulp.LpVariable('y')
problem += x + y  # maximize sum
problem += 2*x + 3*y <= 9
problem += 3*x + 2*y <= 13
problem += x - y <= 1
problem += y <= 2
problem.solve()
for v in problem.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Оба решения находят: `X=2.4`, `Y=1.4`.

Comment: А без доп.модулей возможно это решить? В версии, в которой мы работаем, пишет, что такие модули не найдены(

Comment: @KAS: если нет модулей, значит поставить следует.

Comment: Я понимаю, но мы показываем задачи преподавателю на вузовских компьютерах, и на них я ничего поставить не могу к сожалению

Comment: @KAS если вы можете свой код копировать, значит можете поставить. Если не ясно как можно to vendor зависимости, задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: ладно, снова большое спасибо) Не подскажите еще по Вашему коду, что делает строка for v in problem.variables(): и зачем нужны + перед равно в "проблемах"?

Comment: @KAS: если не ясно чем `=` от `+=` в Питоне отличаются, то задайте отдельный вопрос. Если не знаете, что for-цикл делает в Питоне, то [для экономии времени] лучше начать с любого учебника по Питону (это самые, самые, самые основы). Дополнительно:  [Различия между циклами for и while](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/790505/23044), [Как реализован цикл for? Почему `for x in a: x=1` не меняет `a` список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750868/23044)

Comment: Нет, я знаю это конечно, что += добавляет правую часть к текущему значению функции, просто мне не ясно, зачем это нужно в данном случае. Или неравенства можно суммировать? Тогда понятно. А в цикле я не понял, что значит problem.variables() и что вообще этот цикл делает, если внутри него только строка print? Ну ладно в общем, извините что ерундой отвлекаю

Comment: @KAS: `problem.variables()` это коллекция переменных задачи (x, y в этом случае) -- на английском это очевидно. `print()` здесь печатает решение: `x = 2.4`, `y = 1.4`¶ Каждая `problem +=` конструкция используется, чтобы задачу по кускам собрать (более наглядный метод  постановки задачи вместо использования матрицы `A_ub` и вектора `b_ub` как в первом примере -- они равнозначны)¶ Если написать `problem =` вместо `problem +=`, то `problem` будет указывать не на `pulp.LpProblem()` объект, а на объект создаваемый самым последним неравенством (с типом, выражающим ограничение в pulp)

Comment: Я знаю, что делает принт) Меня просто удивило, зачем вообще вводить этот цикл, когда вроде как проще написать print x.varValue    print y.varValue. Ну видимо это слишком по-любительски, но смотрится все-таки попроще